# how to save output from cassandra table using spark

Tags: scala, cassandra, apache-spark-sql, cassandra-3.0

I want to save the output/rows read from `cassandra` table to a file in either csv or json format. Using, Spark 1.6.3:

```
scala>val results.sqlContext.sql("select * from myks.mytable")
scala>val.write.option("header","true").save("/tmp/xx.csv") -- writes to cfs:// filesystem
```

I am not able to find an option to write to the OS as `csv` or `json` format file.

Appreciate any help!

Comment: What is the code you are having trouble with? What trouble do you have with your code? Do you get an error message? What is the error message? Is the result you are getting not the result you are expecting? What result do you expect and why, what is the result you are getting and how do the two differ? Is the behavior you are observing not the desired behavior? What is the desired behavior and why, what is the observed behavior, and in what way do they differ? Please, provide a [mcve].

Comment: Can you provide a *precise* specification of what it is that you want to happen, including any and all rules, exceptions from those rules, corner cases, special cases, boundary cases, and edge cases? Can you provide sample inputs and outputs demonstrating what you expect to happen, both in normal cases, and in all the exceptions, corner cases, special cases, boundary cases, and edge cases? Please, also make sure to provide a [mcve].

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the spark Cassandra connector to read data from a Cassandra table into spark

https://github.com/datastax/spark-cassandra-connector/blob/master/doc/0_quick_start.md

Comment: thanks, but I did not see the option to save the output to a text/json format file

Comment: yourDataFrame.write.json("your.json")